# A question in number theory based on asymptotics

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I study number theory by myself and couldn't prove this question (Question number 12 , Chapter 13) Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory.

> Let $f(n)$ be a multiplicative function such that if $p$ is prime then $f(p^m) \to 0 $ as $p^m \to \infty$. Prove that $f(n) \to 0$ as $n \to\infty$.

Consider $n= p^{m_1}  p_x$ . Now as $p^{m_1}$ 's  tends to 0 and $f(p^{m_1}) \to 0$  and $f(p_x) = c$ ( finite constant ). Now n in this case tends to infinity, but not necessarily $f(n) \to 0$ . It would be indeterminate form.

So, is there some mistake in question? I didn't tried proving it as I realized this mistake.

Or is there anything wrong with my reasoning. ( I am not able to find anything wrong so resorted to help here).

Comment: Your reasoning is flawed, or at the very least not written up well. What is $p^{m_1}$? What is $p_x$? Why should $p^{m_1}$ tend to infinity? Why is $p_x$ constant in $n$?

Comment: This is Theorem 316 in Hardy & Wright's "An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers".

Comment: @Michael Barz $p$ and $p_x$ are both primes. $p^{m_1} $ tending to infinity is given in hypothesis to prove n tends to $\infty$ .

Comment: @Tim Why should $n$ only have 2 distinct prime factors? What if $n = 30$?

Comment: @Michael Barz I am giving an example where what author asks to be proved can't be proved.

Comment: @Tim Ah, I misunderstood what you were saying. But this is still wrong. If $f(p_x)$ is constant, then $f(n) = f(p^{m_1}) \cdot c$ still goes to 0. If $a_1, a_2, ...$ goes to 0, then so does $ca_1, ca_2, ca_3, ...,$ regardless of how large $c$ is. Try constructing an actual counterexample function and you'll see the problem.

Comment: @Michael Barz Ok,  I got it. Thanks!!

Comment: @James You asked for a detailed answer : I have provided it, but let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Introduction

Ok, so you want a more detailed answer to this question.

Let me explain :

- How I would attack this question, and
- Proof writing for such a question.

---

###### On your attempt

First, a comment on your attempt.

Note that you don't get an indeterminate form : a constant times zero, is zero. An indeterminate form is when you are multiplying something whose limit is *infinity* versus something going to zero : only then can the "multiplication rule for limits" fail. It doesn't fail if both limits are real numbers, because in that case their product makes sense.

So your reasoning is spot on : but it's only a specific case.

---

##### Understanding the problem

Let us start with what a multiplicative function is : it's an arithmetic function $f$ such that $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb N$ coprime.

The most important thing about an arithmetic function, is to note that it's determined by its values at prime powers. In other words, we know that :
$$
f(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{\alpha_i}) = \prod_{i=1}^n f(p_i^{\alpha_i})
$$
where the $\alpha_i>0$ are positive integers and the $p_i$ are distinct primes.

So it's not completely unexpected, that the given statement is true. If the building blocks have a pattern, they build to form a more general pattern.

However, what isn't the right approach, is the kind of approach being suggested by the attempt. The point is, that there are infinitely many primes, so studying particular sequences of primes is not going to resolve the situation, because you are going to leave out the "rest" of the primes in that process.

So we need to go by definition.

That is , we should show that :

> For every $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $f(n)<\epsilon$.

For ease of speech, I call $f(n)$ as the $f$-value of $n$ in some parts of this answer.

---

##### The key ideas

Let us  first decode the given assumption. While it was worded a little too ambiguously for my liking, Apostol clarifies it to be :

> For all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N>0$ such that whenever $p$ is prime, $m$ is a positive integer such that $p^m > N$, we have $f(p^m)<\epsilon$.

Now, this is interesting. This is basically telling you : if you give me $\epsilon$, I'll give you an $N$ such that *all prime powers after* $N$ are handled by $\epsilon$. You need to tell me how to improve this $N$ so that all numbers, and not just prime powers, are handled.

But the point is simple : how do we handle numbers that aren't prime powers? Well, let's take a number that's not a prime power. It's definitely a product of prime powers, though!

And now, let's talk about those prime powers in that product. If a prime power is larger than $N$, then it's controlled for us. If it's not larger than $N$, then thankfully it's part of *only a finite bunch of prime powers* that sit below $N$! Finiteness allows us to take the worst-case and adjust $N$ so that it gets bounded as nicely as needed. And that, my friend, is the game in a nutshell.

---

##### The worst case

Take $\epsilon=1$. Recalling the definition of the convergence Apostol is referring to , I quote :

> For all $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N>0$ such that whenever $p$ is prime, $m$ is a positive integer such that $p^m > N$, we have $f(p^m)<\epsilon$.

Now, let $\epsilon=1$. There is then a $D>0$ such that whenever $p$ is prime and $m$ is a positive integer such that $p^m>D$, we have $|f(p^m)| < 1$. We just used the definition above to confirm this (note that this definition is given in the same question in Apostol, at least in the version I'm consulting).

The point is, that if a prime power has a high $f$-value, then it must be smaller than $D$. In other words, our worst-case scenario must come from prime powers below $D$. Let $S' = \{n = p^m :n \leq D\}$ be the set of all prime powers below $D$. Define :
$$
T = \max_{S'' \subset S'} \prod_{s \in S''} |f(s)|.
$$
then $T$ is a finite constant that captures the *worst* possible behaviour away from $D$, in the sense that any number which has prime factors solely consisting of prime factors smaller than $D$, can have $f$-value at most $T$. Thus, we've controlled out worst-case factor.

Now, any prime power bigger than $D$ will only bring down the absolute value if multiplied with another number, because it's $f$-value has modulus smaller than $1$.

---

##### Key principle and explanation for key claim

Now, let's look at a term like $p_1^{\alpha_1}...p_m^{\alpha_m}$. Let's imagine that *one* of the $|f(p_l^{\alpha_l})|$ was smaller than $\epsilon$, and the rest are all smaller than, say $1$. Then,$|f|$ applied to the entire term is smaller than $\epsilon$ by the multiplicative property. We realize from this simple bit of thought, the key principle that  *one prime power having controlled $f$-value controls the $f$-value of the entire number, since the rest of the prime powers are already under control*.

Let's keep ourselves flexible and let $\epsilon>0$. We will also consider a $1>\delta>0$ (note : the $1>$ part is also important) that we will allow to depend upon $\epsilon$, and for this $\delta$ let's get an $N_{\delta}$ such that $p^m > N_{\delta}$ implies $|f(p^m)|<\delta$.

So what does this mean? We have controlled to high degree, the value of $f$ for prime powers *above* $N_{\delta}$. We ask ourselves in line with the key principle : is it true, that every *large enough* number is divisible by some prime power above $N_{\delta}$? The answer to that is the key to the entire process, and is an absolute *YES*.

The idea is to take the product of all prime powers below $N_{\delta}$. If a number is above that product, then it will be divisible by at least one prime power which is bigger than $N_{\delta}$ , as we show below.

---

##### Key claim

> Claim : Let $P = \{n=p^m, n \leq N_{\delta}\}$ and let $K = \prod_{s \in P} s$. Then, for all $L>K$ there exists a prime power not in $P$ which divides $L$.

Proof : Suppose not. Then, every prime power which divides $L$ belongs in $P$. Now, $L$ is made of a product of prime powers, but each such prime power must be in $P$, so there is some subset $S' \subset P$ such that $L = \prod_{s \in S'} s$. But that clearly means that $L$ divides $K$! So $L \leq K$, a contradiction.$\blacksquare$

What we've basically found, is a constant $K$ such that every number above $K$ has a prime power factor whose $f$-value is well controlled.

---

##### Grouping the prime powers

The key principle, combined with the claim, tells us that every large enough number can be controlled, because it contains one controlling factor, and one controlling factor is enough.

Let us now take this to the next level. Remember $D$? We had defined $D$ such that whenever $p^m>D$ we have $|f(p^m)|<1$.

If we have a number $M$, we can consider this decomposition into three parts :

- Those coming from prime powers that lie below $D$.
- Those coming from prime powers that lie between $D$ and $K$ ($D>K$ could happen, but for the same of rigour we note that the claim works if $K$ is replaced by a larger number as well, so we can take $K$ to be large enough in the claim to ensure that $D<K$ and hence this range makes sense).
- Those coming from prime powers that lie above $K$.

Now, the first group contributes at most $T$ in absolute value. The second group, if it exists at all, consists of prime powers $p^m$ such that $|f(p^m)|<1$, so if anything they will reduce the modulus.

The third group contributes at most $\delta$ : this is because if you break it into prime powers, then each prime power has $f$-value at most $\delta$, so if there are $m$ prime powers (and by the claim, $m \geq 1$) then the $f$-value of this group is at most $\delta^m \leq \delta$  because $\delta<1$.

Finally, we conclude that the total contribution is at most $\delta T$. Of course, for this to be less than $\epsilon$, we must have $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{T}$, and we can now finish the formal proof!

---

##### Formal Proof

Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{T}$. Consider $N_{\delta}$ and $K$ defined above corresponding to $\delta$. We claim that for any $L>K$ we have $|f(L)|<\epsilon$.

To see why, we write $L = A \times B \times C$, where :

- $A$ is the product of the prime powers dividing $L$, which are smaller than $D$.
- $B$ is the product of the prime powers dividing $L$ which are between $K$ and $D$.
- $C$ is the product of the prime powers dividing $L$ which are bigger than $K$.

We know that $f(L)=f(A)f(B)f(C)$. Since $C>1$, it follows that $|f(C)|<\delta$. We know that $|f(B)|<1$ and $|f(A)|\leq T$. Therefore, we get that $|f(L)| \leq \delta T = \epsilon$, completing the proof.

Comment: In the Worst Case : You wrote: There is an D such that whenever $p^m>D$ we have $|f(p^m)|<1$. Can  you prove it?

Comment: @James I'll add the proof shortly, thanks for asking for clarification.

Comment: @James It follows by inserting $\epsilon = 1$ into the definition given by Apostol for the convergence $f(p^m) \to 1$. I edited to clarify this, but I spent some time framing it so you'd get it in the best possible manner.

Comment: Thanks! You are very kind person. Thanks!

Comment: @James Welcome! I was actually waiting for your feedback for a day or two, so I almost forgot about this post based on how old it is. I hope it was a decent illustration of reuns' answer, which by itself was a great piece of thinking.

Comment: Ya your answer is great but I am afraid it became too long. Although,it is very detailed and I respect the effort you put in writing and formulating the answer.

Comment: @James It was too long? I see! Interesting, I usually write lengthy posts to make sure that I can cater to a broader set of issues and finer points in each answer. I agree that I do repeat some points, so I'll keep this in mind for future answers. Thanks a lot for your feedback, though. I will probably keep things more concise when I can.

Comment: I really appreciate the work you put in."Interesting, I usually write lengthy posts to make sure that I can cater to a broader set of issues and finer points in each answer".It also helps to cater wide range of audience because the education background of people here are varied.

Comment: @James You're absolutely right, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

If $n > N!$ then some prime power $q^r>N$ divides $n$.

Let $h(N)= \sup_{p^k> N} |f(p^k)|$ and $C=\prod_{|f(p^k)|>1}|f(p^k)|$, then $$|f(n)|\le \ ...$$

Comment: 'If n>N! then some prime power $q^r>N $divides n" How can I prove it?

Comment: The product of all prime powers $\le N$ is $\le N!$

Comment: I think there is a typo, it should be stated as"If $n>N!$ then some prime power $q^{r}<N$ divides $n$". Some  $q^{r}>N$ do not necessarily divide $N!$.